# Why are buttons in Android Studio round by default?

Tags: android, xml

[image]

Shouldn't the default be square? Why is it rounded and stretched out with rounded corners?
I'm just starting to learn Android development and don't have much experience， and I haven't made any modifications.

Comment: What theme are you using?  Could the theme be applying a custom drawable background?  Views are always rectangular, the drawing here is just only taking up a circular portion of the view.

Comment: The default theme Base.Theme.MyApplication is used and has not been modified in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Google introduced material design, which uses round buttons by default. If you want to retain the old style of buttons (rectangular), one of the options is to change the attributes in your XML file. Go to the "Design" tab, select your button and then in the "Common Attributes" panel, find and set the "cornerRadius" attribute to "0dp". This should make your button rectangular.

But this will change only the selected button. If you want to change all buttons, you should update your app's theme in the styles.xml file